# It is possible to specify the scrollbar image with HTML5?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I need to display a custom scrollbar. I would like to avoid using a jQuery plugin if possible. So can I so something like this with HTML5 & CSS3 ? :

```
.myScrollableBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;

  /* Display scrollbar if content is bigger than the box */
  overflow: auto;

  /* This doesn't work, but can I do something similar? */
  scrollbar-image: url(/images/myscrollbar.png); 
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's actually possible, if browser does support styling of toolbar *elements* (= is based on WebKit). Although it's not mentioned in many tutorials (such as [this brilliant one](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/), for example), you can just use `background-url` property to use custom image instead of color.

For example, [in this page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/) I've changed (in Chrome Developer Tools) styling to...

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: url('http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/themes/CSS-Tricks-10/images/header-demos.jpg');
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

... and voila, I have some cyanid scroller. )

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, but it is not supported in every browser. Webkit (Chrome etc) has support for this using css:

```
-webkit-scrollbar
-webkit-scrollbar-button
-webkit-scrollbar-track
-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
-webkit-scrollbar-corner
-webkit-resizer
```

Read more: https://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

In Internet Explorer you can user css like
*scrollbar-face-color* or *-ms-scrollbar-face-color*

```
-ms-scrollbar-3dlight-color
-ms-scrollbar-arrow-color
-ms-scrollbar-base-color
-ms-scrollbar-darkshadow-color
-ms-scrollbar-face-color
-ms-scrollbar-highlight-color
-ms-scrollbar-shadow-color
-ms-scrollbar-track-color
```

Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As far as I know, other browsers do not support this at the moment.

Answer (score -3):

no, that is not really possible. The scrollbar used by the browser is not an image placed inside the html page. It is part of the browser logic. You cannot simply replace that.

Comment: Well, sometimes even more unimaginable things are made possible by these moderny browsers. )

Comment: @raina77ow: sure, you could for example take the browsers source code and reprogram it. That certainly is possible, true.