# Custom Scrollbar Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

[image]

I got a PSD web mockup here I'm having a hard time with this part the scrollbar. I can't seem to find good example like this I feel like this is not even possible. Please if you guys have any idea how to do this let me know.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727422/it-is-possible-to-specify-the-scrollbar-image-with-html5

Comment: Webkit is only applicable in chrome